# ThreeJS mesh becomes invisible when its center is out of camera view

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create a map with different meshes. The problem I'm struggling with is that meshes are disappearing when the center of the mesh is out of camera view.

Here's a GIF of the problem:
https://gfycat.com/CornyBrilliantChuckwalla

I'm using THREE.WebGLRenderer 71.

Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: edit the question describing the problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set:

```
object.frustumCulled = false;
```

where "object" is the THREE.Object3D() that is flickering.